# How do I simulate an ItoProcess that is not supposed to become negative?

Tags: simulation, stochastic-calculus

I have a process that is similar to a Cox Ingersoll Ross process. Like a CIR process this process does not become negative. However, when I define the process with ItoProcess and I simulate it with RandomFunction the process eventually becomes negative. This is also the case when the CIR process is converted to an ItoProcess:

```
proc = ItoProcess[CoxIngersollRossProcess[0.03, 0.081, 0.12, 0.03]]
ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 100, 1}, 3], AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

It should be somehow possible to make this simulation because when RandomFunction simulates a CoxIngersollRossProcess directly, then the process remains positive.

```
proc = CoxIngersollRossProcess[0.03, 0.081, 0.12, 0.03]
ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 100, 1}, 3], AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

My process is a bit more complicated, namely:

```
ItoProcess[{{0. + 
1. (0.000543365 + 0.0332072 Sqrt[x[t]] + 
   0.00206415 x[t]^(3/2))}, {{0.081 Sqrt[x[t]]}}, x[t]}, {{x}, {0.01}}, {t, 0}]
```

Comment: Try using `Method -> "Milstein"` on the `RandomFunction`.It didn't go negative as often. It's likely some kind of internal precision issue or bug, or maybe Milstein is just a much better method. The KloedenPlatenSchurz method also did well but it did go negative in a couple of cases. All the others went negative very often.

Comment: ^just to put some numbers to the above, `"Milstein"` produced valid non-negative paths in 70.8% of 1000 random paths, while `"KloedenPlatenSchurz"` only got 12.2% valid non-negative paths . Adding `WorkingPrecision->100` to RandomFunction improved both by about 5%. This is likely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If your are interested in crash probabilty,  make the  border absorbing at 0 and count the hits. If absorption at 0 is not possible, eg because its the center in 2d, mirror the negative Brownian bridges into a positive one.
In any case, the square roots make sense for Abs x[t] only. possbly a bug somwhere in adaption of time step near 0 where the standard deviation of

```
dW ~ sqrt dt
```

is not small.